# laravel 4 route::controller not working

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new to laravel. i had this problem when try to play around with route and controller.
i have this controller

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController {
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $photos = Auth::user()->photos()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return View::make('dashboard.index', array('photos' => $photos));
    }
public function action_insert_test_data()
{   
    $logged_in_user = Auth::user();

    for( $x = 0; $x < 10; $x++ ) {
        $email = rand().'@gmail.com';
        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($email);
        $user->save();

        $logged_in_user->followers()->attach($user->id);
        if( $x >= 5 ) {
            $logged_in_user->following()->attach($user->id);
        }
    }
}
```

and i try to route all action in this controller to dashboard page with

```
Route::controller('dashboard', 'DashboardController');
```

but i didn't work, instead i got an error message like this

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

what should i do? where did i go wrong? i'm using laravel 4.1
thanks for your attention

Comment: laravel 3 or laravel 4?

Comment: i'm using laravel 4.1

Comment: you are using laravel 3 pattern.... it wont work in laravel 4. you want this as restful or resource controller. if you don't know what is them, refer to [**this**](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers)

Comment: yes, i got this from tutorial on laravel 3, and i try to use restful controller. then how should i use restful controller to route this 2 method? i'm very confused now. @_@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods in your class should be named `getIndex` and `getInsertTestData`.

See [Laravel Implicit Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers)

Comment: still not working, i try to comment the second method and rename the first to getIndex, and still the same error message

Comment: EDIT: its worked on getIndex method. but the second method still not working.

Comment: What URL did you use for the second method?  Should be example.com/dashboard/insert-test-data

Comment: i try to route this 2 methods on 1 page example.com/dashboard. the first method is to view the page, and the second to create data to database and use it in page.

Comment: Then you should call `$this->getInsertTestData();` inside your `getIndex` method.  Also you can name `getInsertTestData` whatever you want since it's not a separate page.